# How to make Rounded corner for the mat-select Dropdown on all corners

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have a `mat-select` Dropdown in `Angular`, `Angular Material` and `css`

How can I create a rounded corner for the mat-select dropdown?

[image: Rounded Corners for Dropdown]

**EDIT**

I am using below css to make the Dropdown Panel appear with Rounded Corners. But it seems the scroll bar is overriding this...

```
.custom-panel-siteId {
  margin: 40px 0px !important;
  min-width: 310px !important;
  margin-left: 17px !important;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Even with the given `css`, the rounded corners are not coming.. Any clues? Is it because of the scrollbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is doable, you can do with the below CSS. But you need to note a few points

- This change will be applied for all select components and elements that have the class `cdk-overlay-pane`, we cannot isolate the fix to only one select
- Its better you do not do this fix, because we cannot be sure where it will impact the UI

css

```
// to add curved edges
.cdk-overlay-pane {
  overflow: hidden !important;
  border-radius: 5px !important;
}
```

html

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-field-custom">
  <mat-select
    class="frequency-dimensions"
    formControlName="frequency"
    (change)="disableSubmitButton=false"
    disableOptionCentering
    panelClass="custom-panel-frequency"
  >
    <mat-option value="daily" selected>Daily</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="total">Total</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="total">Total</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="total">Total</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="total">Total</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="total">Total</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="total">Total</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="total">Total</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: `cdk-overlay-pane` is not used in `html`?

Comment: Using `mat-form-field` is changing the style of the `mat-select`. Is it not possible to only use `mat-select` without `mat-form-field`?

Comment: @CPK_2011 mat form field is not needed in this example, cdk overlay pane is generated by angular material

Comment: For me with `cdk-overlay-pane`, the rounded corners are not coming for all the sides

Comment: When I use `cdk-overlay-pane`, it is affecting other `mat-select` controls in the same project.

Comment: @CPK_2011 yes it's better not to round the corners because of the global impact on your application